# Type conversion at template non-type argument without constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, c++14

Consider the following code:

```
struct A {
    constexpr operator int() { return 42; }
};

template <int>
void foo() {}

void bar(A a) {
    foo<a>();
}

int main() {
    foo<A{}>();

    const int i = 42;
    foo<i>();  // (1)

    A a{};

    static_assert(i == a, "");
    bar(a);
    foo<a>();  // error here
}
```

Clang 3.7 with c++14 accepts this, while gcc 5.2.0 with c++14 does not, producing the following message:

> ```
> /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler1151027-68-1f801jf/example.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> 26 : error: the value of 'a' is not usable in a constant expression
> foo<a>();
> ^
> 23 : note: 'a' was not declared 'constexpr'
> A a{};
> ^
> Compilation failed
> ```

Changing `a` to be `constexpr` as suggested by gcc fixes the gcc compilation error, but without `constexpr`, which compiler is right?

For me, it seems that `a` should be "usable in constant expression", as `static_assert` ceritifies. Moreover, the fact that `i` can be used the same way (marked `(1)`), and the fact that `bar()` compiles, also makes me think that gcc is wrong.

**UPD**: reported a bug against gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68588

Comment: Changing `const` by `constexpr` works [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bc480f2de523b5e).

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user-defined conversion is allowed by [[expr.const]/(4.1)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4), and I don't see a single applicable bullet point in [[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) that would prevent your expression from being a constant one. In fact, the requirements are so loose that declaring `a` as

```
A a;
```

is [still giving a well-formed program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1953c90933f97b60), even if `a` didn't have a `constexpr` default constructor etc., since the conversion operator is `constexpr` and no members are evaluated.

As you saw yourself, GCC is contradictory in that it allows `a` in the `static_assert` condition but not a template-argument.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that Clang is correct.

Draft for current C++ (n4296) says:

> 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments [temp.arg.nontype]
>
> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression (5.20) of
>   the type of the template-parameter

And 5.20 §4 says (emphasize mine):

> 5.20 Constant expressions [expr.const]
>
> ...
>
> (4) A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, **where the converted
>   expression is a constant expression** and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> (4.1) — user-defined conversions, ...

IFAIK in `foo<a>();` a is converted to int with a constexpr user-defined conversion and as such **is** a converted constant expression.

That being said, we are not far from a edge case here, and my advice would be: do not play with such a construct in production code :-)

Answer (score -2):

As @Jarod42 suggests `a` should be `constexpr`. This is because templates are deduced at compile time, and so non-type arguments also have to be available at compile time. `constexpr` is a promise that they will be available at compile time.

Comment: I am completely aware of the fact that `constexpr` solves the problem (see also my edit).

Comment: If so, then this should tell you which implementation is correct.