# Clarification of converted constant expression definition

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

(Following [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957274/type-conversion-at-template-non-type-argument-without-constexpr), and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872039/invalid-explicitly-specified-argument-in-clang-but-successful-compilation-in-gcc/34017482).)

[expr.const]/4 says that:

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly
>   converted to type T, where the **converted expression** is a constant
>   expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> - ... (list omitted)
>
> and where the **reference binding** (if any) binds directly.

(Emphasis mine.)

There are two points that I do not quite understand here.

First, which expression does "the converted expression" (emphased) refer to?

Consider, for example

```
class A; // assume it can be implicitly converted to `int`
A foo(); // or maybe constexpr
template<int n> void bar();
```

Now, if I write

```
bar<foo()>();
```

then which expression should be constant expression? Should the whole `foo()` expression be constant, or just something like `static_cast<int>(foo())`?

From what I understand from [my recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957274/type-conversion-at-template-non-type-argument-without-constexpr), only the latter needs to be constant. Is this true?

Second, what stage of the whole process does "reference binding" refer to? Does it refer only to cases when the template parameter itself is a reference (`template<int& x>...`)? Or does it require that any reference binding that occurs somewhere during the type conversion or evaluation of converted expression, should be direct? Or does it refer to the case when the non-yet-converted expression is a reference itself (`A& a=...; bar<a>();`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, which expression does "the converted expression" (emphased)
>   refer to?

Implicit conversion introduces a correspondingly initialized temporary:

```
T e = /* original expression */;
```

`e` is the "converted expression". `T = int` in your case.

> then which expression should be constant expression?

`e`.

Moreover, `foo` *and* the conversion operator function that has been implicitly invoked must be constexpr functions as per [[expr.const]/(2.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2).

> Second, what stage of the whole process does "reference binding" refer
>   to?

When `T` is a reference type, that reference - `e` in the above example - shall bind directly. No binding necessitated inside the expression or before it is of interest.

Comment: But if _both_ expressions must be `constexpr`, then why [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db7921267ecacd99) only the latter call fails? Neither `a` neither `x` there is `const`, but `a` has a `constexpr` conversion.

Comment: @Petr That's a completely different example.

Comment: But what is essential in this difference? In all cases the original expression is not constant, is it?

Comment: @Petr The original expression `a` is constant. `x` is not. I've adjusted the answer, however, it was unclear indeed, thanks.

Comment: Ok, with your final edit I think I now understand. `foo()` is anyway evaluated, and therefore it should be `constexpr`. While in `A a; bar<a>();` only the conversion operator is evaluated, and it does not evaluate anything in `a`, so `a` is not required to be `constexpr`. Still your last comment is unclear (though it then seems not quite relevant to main question); what part of standard differentiates between `a` and `x` so that `a` is constant and `x` is not?

Comment: @Petr Sorry. `x` is also a constant expression. Mea culpa. In my head I was already including the l-t-r conversion, which is only applied during the implicit conversion…

Comment: But wait, if `x` is constant, why can't I use it as a template parameter?

Comment: @Petr Simple: `x` *itself* is a constant expression, but the converted expression performed an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion during the implicit conversion. This l-t-r conversion on `x` is, however, not allowed in a constant expression as per [expr.const]/(2.7.1), since `x` is not const.