# Can one use parameter value directly (not its type but value itself) in trailing return type syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, trailing-return-type

Consider the minimal example:

```
template <int>
struct bar { };

int main() 
{
    [](auto i) -> bar<i> { return {}; };
}
```

Or even:

```
template <int>
struct bar {};

template <class I>
auto foo(I i) -> bar<i> {}
```

clang compiles both forms without problems but gcc find the usages invalid [(ex. 1)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tqyAogSOLYDrNNbg), [(ex. 2)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nFfclJRdpv7ltiD9)

The question might look silly however the type of parameter can have the constexpr conversion operator overloaded (in this case type of `i` deduced from value passed to lambda/foo to `int` in constexpr manner) and in this scenario it would be quite convenient not to be forced to do some workarounds to access it directly...

Comment: `auto bar = [](auto i) -> std::enable_if_t<decltype(i)::value == 0> { };` should be fine (and legal).

Comment: @ildjarn yes, but [std::integral_constant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) has overloaded constexpr conversion operator so I thought it should also work without `decltype(i)::value`, or shouldn't it?

Comment: Actually the behavior affects SFINAE in case of function [as well](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1xKhzvXGSCec6tD3). I missed that fact before...

Comment: This is not related to SFINAE. Here's a [minimal example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tqyAogSOLYDrNNbg) that works on clang but not gcc. Language lawyer question?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You're right... I'll try to edit the question to make it better. Thanks!

Comment: Smells like a gcc bug to me...

Comment: I think that the real question is: [**"is `i` a valid `constant-expression`"**](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#nt:constant-expression)?

Comment: `decltype(i){}` is then why `i` shouldn't?

Comment: Both schemes are wrong, since a template parameter must be a constant expression, which in your case the function parameter is not. Naively, we could say that both compilers are right, since any of the templates in the examples is not instantiated.

Comment: @101010 but it might be convertable to a constant expression, no?

Comment: @W.F If you mean the function parameters I believe the answer is no.

Comment: @101010 why do you think so? How does `decltype(i){}` differs from `i` itself in this context?

Comment: @101010: it seems that the error occurs during parsing, though. `i` could be a *constant-expression* in some instantiations of `foo` - shouldn't gcc wait until `foo`'s instantiation to produce an error?

Comment: @W.F `decltype(i)` is  a type.

Comment: @101010 but `decltype(i){}` is an instance. gcc actually agrees that in case of `decltype(i){}` the code is legit for both examples. [ex1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BoBhiRSUrEo2LZ3f), [ex2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F0Zl832ddokqVa2a)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872039/invalid-explicitly-specified-argument-in-clang-but-successful-compilation-in-gcc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a `gcc` bug. I reported it as issue [**#80242**](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80242).

---

`gcc` complains about the validity of `i` as a template argument:

> **error**: template argument 1 is invalid

---

I've followed the [C++ grammar](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram) from [*`trailing-return-type`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#nt:trailing-return-type) to [*`template-argument`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#nt:template-argument), which needs to be a [*`constant-expression`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#nt:constant-expression):

> *template-argument*:
>
> - *constant-expression* **<-**
> - *type-id*
> - *id-expression*

---

The real question then becomes: **"is `i` a valid *`constant-expression`*?"**.

I think the answer is **"yes"**, because [**§8.20.4** *[expr.const]*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4) says:

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only:
>
> - user-defined conversions,
>
> *[...]*
>
> (Note: Such expressions may be used in new expressions, as case expressions, as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed, as array bounds, **and as non-type template arguments**. )

There is a sequence of implicit conversions that, starting from `i`, will produce a *converted constant expression* which is a *constant expression*. Given:

```
template <int>
struct bar { };

template <class I>
auto foo(I i) -> bar<i> { }

int main()
{
    foo(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}); // (0)
}
```

- In the context of the function call at **(0)**, the argument `i` is an instance of `std::integral_constant<int, 1>`.
- [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) provides a `constexpr` user-defined conversion to the underlying `value_type`.
- *Converted constant expressions* explicitly allow *user-defined conversions*, as seen above in [**§8.20.4** *[expr.const]*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4).
- `std::integral_constant::operator value_type()` will return the non-type template argument `1`. This is a *core constant expression* as it doesn't violate any of the rules specified in [**§8.20.2** *[expr.const]*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2).
- Therefore, the *converted constant expression* is a *constant expression*.

Comment: You still have to demonstrate that the converted expression is a constant expression, but I think this is basically right. An example will also help, since this is a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: @T.C. I updated my answer - let me know if my proof looks solid or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that both your examples are wrong. Based on the standard wording *5.20 Constant expressions [expr.const]/p2.7*:

> <sup>2</sup> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression
>   unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract
>   machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:j
>
> ...
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to:

Function parameters can't be constant expressions since in order to pass them as template parameters you're applying lvalue to rvalue conversion on them.

In both CLANG and GCC if you instatiate the templates you are going to get an error based on the wording above. I believe that since in the examples non of the template is instatiated no diagnostic is required thus both compilers are correct.

Comment: Nope, you don't necessarily have to apply an l-to-r conversion.